# error in connecting to Oracle database

Tags: hadoop

The requirement is to import table from Oracle database to HDFS using sqoop.
I have placed the jdbc jar file in /sooqp/lib/ in cloudera VMWare.However, when I check through *ping oradb*, it shows *unknown host oradb*. As a result of this I am not able to proceed with further steps.Am I missing out on steps pertaining to Oracle db set up on cloudera machine? How do I connect to it?
Please advise on what could be the issue.

Comment: Depending on what oracle driver you are using, oradb, may not be a host at all. It might be a "service name".  If it is a real host (an IP address), you'll need to put an entry into your .hosts file for it, to ping oradb.

Comment: Thanks ! It was helpful.

Comment: as per the syntax for connecting to oracle db via sqoop, it is :
 
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:system/system@<IP address>:1521:xe  --username <username> -P--table <database name>.<table name>
however when I check for IP address using SQLPlus it's giving in IPV6 format9fe80::f486:bde2:953d:2061%27). so each time I run sqoop command, it's giving error messages. "invalid connection string format, a valid format is:"host:port:sid".Is there any other way out?

Please advise on what should be the proper syntax in such cases.